# Cómo hacer una función que devuelva una lista con las posiciones de una letra a elegir dentro de una cadena también a elegir

Tags: python, python-3.x

Si introduzco **a** como letra y farola obtengo: [1,1] Si introduzco **r** como letra y roberto obtengo: [0,0] Me recorre la lista que después debo de sacar por pantalla con las posiciones, pero las posiciones que se añaden no son las correctas.

---

```
def buscaLetra(l,c):
    listacadena = list(c)
    posicioneslista = []
    for i in listacadena:
        if l in i:
            posicioneslista.append(listacadena.index(i))
    print (posicioneslista)

letracadena = str(input("Introduzca una letra: "))
cadena = str(input("Introduzca una cadena: "))
buscaLetra(letracadena,cadena)
```

Comment: Buenas, corrige el titulo para que describa el problema (y no un titulo como de ejercicio). Y dentro de la publicación, explica el error y que quieres obtener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si quieres que te devuelva el indice de la letra `a` por ejemplo, puedes usar un contador de esta forma

```
def buscaLetra(l,c):
    contador = 0
    listacadena = list(c)
    posicioneslista = []
    for i in listacadena:
        if l in i:
            posicioneslista.append(contador)
        contador += 1
    print (posicioneslista)

letracadena = str(input("Introduzca una letra: "))
cadena = str(input("Introduzca una cadena: "))
buscaLetra(letracadena,cadena)
```

salida

```
introduzca letra: a
introduzca una cadena: francisca

>>> [2, 8]
```

no se si es esto lo que buscas

Comment: Sí era eso!! Me interesaba más haber usado index pero aun así me sirve. Gracias!!

Comment: si te sirve no olvides marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los índices puedes obtenerlos de este modo.

> **Nota:** Además estoy mostrando la cadena para que puedas verificar.

```
def buscaLetra(l,c):
    posicioneslista = []
    print(listacadena)
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(c) if x == l]
    print(indices)

letracadena = str(input("Introduzca una letra: "))
cadena = str(input("Introduzca una cadena: "))
buscaLetra(letracadena,cadena)
```

Comment: No es necesario convertir la cadena en una lista, enumerate toma un iterable, una cadena ya es un iterable.

Comment: Creo que lo he corregido.